# How do I tap only once on touchable opacity placed inside a scrollview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I already researched similar questions on the topic, so please don't be in a hurry to close this question.

I have a search screen, where I type a search term and I fetch listed results. Once fetched, I want to tap on any one of them and navigate to that page details object. My initial first tap is never been detected, but my second is. My component:

```js
return (
  <View>
    <TextInput
      value={query}
      placeholder="Type Here..."
      onChangeText={(search) => setQuery(search)}
    />
    {fetching ? (
      <Spinner
        visible={fetching}
        textContent={'Fetching data...'}
        textStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
      />
    ) : null}
    {items ? (
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={1}
          horizontal={false}
          data={items}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('Item Details', { id: item.id })
              }>
              <ItemDisplay item={item} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    ) : null}
  </View>
);
```

My `ItemDisplay` is just a row of item's photo and item's id. Nothing fancy.

As suggested on the similar questions, I do use `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>` and `<ItemDisplay item={item} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" />` However it doesn't help m, I still need to tap twice. Any ideas on how do I fix this? I am testing it on android, if that matters.

I also tried `<ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="on-drag" keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"} >` but this doesnt help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are facing an issue clicking an item when the Keyboard is present.

If so you can simply pass `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` as `always` to your `FlatList` and then the children of the list will receive taps when an item is pressed.

Also, you shouldn't be using a `ScrollView` to wrap your `Flatlist`, if they are both having the same orientation, `numColumns` isn't required as you have passed it as `1`

You can read more about `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` at https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps

Take a look at this [Live Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/list-with-keyboard) to see it in action.

Comment: Perfect Explanation.

Comment: this solved my problem. First Tap for TouchableOpacity was not working. key board was closed but it was not working this helps